# How to use special characters with $form->end() in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using CakePHP 1.3. I know, old version but that is what I have for now. I am trying to have a button with the text "¡Listo!". The code I have tried is:

```
echo $form->end('aqu&iacute;', array('escape' => false));
echo $form->end('aqu&iacute;');
```

The result is always this:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq73v.png]

What I want is this:

[image]

I have achieved the use of special characters using `$html->link()` but I do not know how to achieve it using `$form->end()`. See how I did it for `$html->link()`:

```
echo  $html->link('&iexcl;Listo!', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'change_email'), array('target' => '_self', 'class'=>'js-change-email', 'escape' => false));
```

Do you know how to use special characters with `$form->end()` in CakePHP? Thank you.

Comment: I don't have a copy of this to test with, but did you try `echo $form->end(array('label' => 'aqu&iacute;', 'escape' => false));`?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Wow, this works: `echo $form->end(array('label' => '&iexcl;Listo!', 'escape' => false));`. Thank you so much! Please write it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `end` function of the Form helper takes only a single parameter. If it's null, it assumes you already output the submit button yourself and just outputs the form end. If it's a string, it's used as the label for the button. If it's an array, it finds the label for the button with the `label` key, and uses the rest as options.

In short, use:

```
echo $form->end(array('label' => 'aqu&iacute;', 'escape' => false));
```